# Very slow performance on listobject.range(x,y).value =

Tags: excel, vba, listobject, excel-tables

So I have got 2 listobject that I merge and i'd like to get the data timestamped after they are merged successfully.
It all works out pretty ok, but this little piece of code takes almost 2 minutes to finish.
2020-11-04 10:46:34
2020-11-04 10:48:13
There just has to be a faster way. Any ideas?
(lotarget and losource are declared and assigned listobjects on the same sheet)

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = false
dtoday = Date
sCreator = Application.UserName

For i = 0 To 350
    loTarget.Range(i, 7).Value = dtoday
    loTarget.Range(i, 8).Value = sCreator
Next i


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Column of ListObject

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim loTarget As ListObject
    Set loTarget = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
    
    Dim dtoday As Date
    dtoday = Now ' Now for time, Date for date.
    Dim sCreator As String
    sCreator = Application.UserName
    
    ' For data rows 1 to 350:
'    loTarget.DataBodyRange(1, 7).Resize(350).Value = dtoday
'    loTarget.DataBodyRange(1, 8).Resize(350).Value = sCreator
    
    ' For all data rows:
    loTarget.DataBodyRange.Columns(7).Value = dtoday
    loTarget.DataBodyRange.Columns(8).Value = sCreator
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Ended up using both ideas for my project! Time went down to pretty much instant.

Answer (score 0):

You could write all values of a column at once. I assume that `loTarget` is your listObject. Use something like

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
With loTarget.Range   
    .Range("G2").Resize(.Rows.Count-1, 1).Value = Date
    .Range("H2").Resize(.Rows.Count-1, 1).Value = Application.UserName
End With
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

I am skipping the top row as this holds likely the column header. Note that "G2" is relative to the table and not the worksheet cell "G2" (unless your table starts as cell "A1").

Maybe speed could also be improved by temporarily deactivating calculation.